# Why are there a ton of Logcat processes slowing down phone?

Tags: performance, logging

I noticed a major slowdown on 2.2.2 Android, and it looks as though it's caused by too many logcat processes. With adb shell, I ran `ps | wc -l` and there were about 400 processes, after running `killall logcat` I ran the ps count again and there were around 200.

Even something as simple as `ls` would take like 10 seconds before, and after cleaning up all those Logcats it was instantaneous.

Is this a known bug in Android?

Comment: I'm not sure what you were doing before this situation was established, but I don't know of such a bug. I just ran an `adb shell "ps|grep logcat"` against my device, and it returned nothing (crosschecked, not a single logcat process running). Maybe something specific to your device/ROM? Or to what you where doing just before?

Comment: It can be caused by an app you've installed on your phone...

Comment: Shywim, I don't remember any apps that mess with logcat. Izzy, are you using an app that has Logcat enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with the Applocker app: http://code.google.com/p/applocker/issues/detail?id=8

It creates too many Linux processes, causing devices to slow way down due to lack of memory.